# Can we restart kubelet without affecting the running pods

Tags: kubernetes

I have configure kubelet to run properly for some days. However, currently, i want to add some image gc parameters to kubelet. I am now curiously about whether i can just add the command parameters and restart kubelet.

Any thing i should take care before of after doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It should be completely safe to bring Kubelet down for a short while.  If it is down too long (40 seconds, I think), the master might detect the node as dead, though :)

Comment: any more info about the communication healthcheck time between kubelet and apiserver?